# (Mysql Android Inserting Values) Inserts blank rows without data

Tags: android, mysql, insert, rows, is-empty

Whenever I try to insert data from an android app, through xampp server 
It inserts new blank rows but no data is inserted

Here's my code

Registration Java File

```
public class Register extends Activity {

EditText ET_fname,ET_lname,ET_mail,ET_phone,ET_subject,ET_pass;
String fname,lname,mail,phone,subject,pass;


@Override
protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    ET_fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
    ET_lname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);
    ET_mail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mail);
    ET_phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    ET_subject=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject);
    ET_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
}
public void userReg(View view)
{
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {

        fname = ET_fname.getText().toString();
        lname = ET_lname.getText().toString();
        mail = ET_mail.getText().toString();
        phone = ET_phone.getText().toString();
        subject = ET_subject.getText().toString();
        pass = ET_pass.getText().toString();
        String method = "Register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method, fname, lname, mail, phone, subject, pass);
        finish();
    }

}
}
```

Background Activities

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx=ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url="http://10.0.2.2/staff/register.php";
    String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/staff/login.php";
    String method=params[0];
    if(method.equals("Register"))
    {

        String fname=params[1];
        String lname=params[2];
        String mail=params[3];
        String phone=params[4];
        String subject=params[5];
        String pass=params[6];
        try {
            URL url=new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=
(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data= URLEncoder.encode("fname","UTF-8")+" = 
"+URLEncoder.encode(fname,"UTF-8")+" & "+
                    URLEncoder.encode("lname","UTF-8")+" = 
"+URLEncoder.encode(lname,"UTF-8")+" & "+
                    URLEncoder.encode("mail","UTF-8")+" = "+URLEncoder.encode(mail,"UTF-8")+" & "+
                    URLEncoder.encode("phone","UTF-8")+" = "+URLEncoder.encode(phone,"UTF-8")+" & "+
                    URLEncoder.encode("subject","UTF-8")+" = "+URLEncoder.encode(subject,"UTF-8")+" & "+
                    URLEncoder.encode("pass","UTF-8")+" = "+URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Here's my insertion php file

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require "init.php";

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$mail = $_POST["mail"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


//$name = "sdf";
//$password = "sdf";
//$email = "sdf@r54";

$sql = "INSERT INTO staff_db 
VALUES('$fname','$lname','$mail','$phone','$subject', '$password');";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
}
else
echo '{"message":"Injected Successfully."}';

?>
```